# matTooltip on material icon

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I've a little concern I was not able to fix so far.
I'm trying to enable a material tooltip which is provided by Angular on a material icon by Angular.
So, I've tried multiple things I found online but none of it works for my issue.
I already tried applying the mattooltip on a normal button, for the button it's works perfectly fine, so I definitely have no problem with the import module and the other stuff.
The only thing which doesn't work is the tooltip on an material icon.
Maybe you have an idea of the solution, I think I'm missing something really simple but I can't figure it out....

Here's what I've tried so far to enable it on the icon:

```
<span class="material-icons" matTooltip ="TEST">wifi</span>
```

Comment: nothing looks like wrong with your code https://angular-xrrwqb-3vuymd.stackblitz.io/  . post your `ts` code

Answer (score 0):

To apply mat tool tip you have to make sure that you actually imported in **app.module.ts** the angular material mattooltip like this.

```
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
imports: [
    MatTooltipModule,
  ],
 providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Also make sure that you have a theme imported in your **style.css**

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```